Download secure files doesn't download files
I am currently working on a CI Pipeline to create and sign docker images; I uploaded the delegated key for signing to GitLab.
During the pipeline, I use download secure file to retrieve the file.
My problem now is that, as you can see below, the script reports that it has downloaded the key /var/certs/, but after using a ls on the directory, the file is not there.
Before, I had already tried to store the key inside a VARIABLE and use echo to write the content in the file, but there I lost the new lines, which docker trust doesn't like.
I also tried running on moving the repository to gitlab.com, because I wasn't sure if the Server of my university is up to date, but the execution still fails.

Below, you will see the deployment stage of the pipeline.
deploy:
  stage: deploy
  image: docker:latest
  services:
    - docker:latest
  variables:
    SECURE_FILES_DOWNLOAD_PATH: '/var/certs'
  only:
    - master
  script:
    - apk update
    - apk add curl
    - apk add bash
    - curl --silent "https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/incubation-engineering/mobile-devops/download-secure-files/-/raw/main/installer" | bash
    - ls -la /var/certs/
    - ls -la .secure_files/
    - echo $SIGNING_KEY_PASSWORD | docker trust key load /var/certs/10505ee4d3913ea70a8d69e19df1a59dc5af99920f9ba4a1b11714b383da4a00.key --name gitlab
    # 'docker info' command is used to debug the job.
    - docker info

My command to start the gitlab runner is the followin.
sudo gitlab-runner register -n  --url "https://gitlab.com/"  --registration-token TOKEN  --executor docker --description "My Docker Runner"  --docker-image "docker:24.0.5"  --docker-privileged

